# What is the std::uniform_random_bit_generator concept and how do I use it?

Tags: c++, templates, random, c++20, c++-concepts

I am writing a class that samples from a specific known probability distribution. Since the quality of random number generators can vary, I want my class to be templated on the user's choice of random engine. I want to use the concept `std::uniform_random_bit_generator` to do that. So my class will take an object `t` of type `T` where `T` is an `std::uniform_random_bit_generator`. I then want to sample from my distribution by using the output of invoking `t` (using calculus).

The problem I am running into is that *I* don't understand from the definition of `std::uniform_random_bit_generator` what the output of invoking `t` is and how I should use that output in the most general way. If I knew, for instance, that `t` would always return an integer between `t::min()` and `t::max()`, then I would be able to finish my class. However, invoking `t` could return a double or some other type that is non-trivial to work with.

How should I sample from a distribution using an object `t` of type `T` that satisfies the general concept `std::uniform_random_bit_generator`?

Comment: So... why don't you just do those things? The [concept requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_random_bit_generator) spell out pretty explicitly what you need to provide.

Comment: @NicolBolas because I am having difficulty reading the concept requirements. Hence, "What is the ```std::uniform_random_bit_generator``` concept?" It looks like an ```std::uniform_random_bit_generator``` needs to be both invocable and have ```G::min()``` and ```G::max()``` members functions. Does that mean I MUST use a function object? If so, this question probably reduces to "what is a function object and how do I use one?" If not, then what are my options?

Comment: You are correct in your assumtions, thus your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses).

Comment: While I believe the first version of the question was the best for Stack Overflow, it didn't receive any responses. I have edited the question with my specific problem.